# Slow booting Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 16 and upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10. Now it has long boot time and sometimes it's too slow to switch between tabs. How can I decrease its boot time?

Comment: Are you using any shells? What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using GNOME shell.